# Is it possible to change the Great Expectations logo shown in Great_Expectations data docs

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, great-expectations

I received tremendous help visualizing Great_Expectations Data Docs from Apache Spark both with Databricks and Synapse see [How to Save Great Expectations results to File From Apache Spark - With Data Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68023413/how-to-save-great-expectations-results-to-file-from-apache-spark-with-data-doc/68364259#68364259)

I was wondering if it was possible to customize the logo shown, see image.

[image]

I would like to change the logo to my own logo - or would that be breaking somekind of copyright

Comment: That would be a violation of copyright law and theft of property if you don't have written authorization from them to do so.  Consult an attorney for legal advice.

Comment: Hi Ken White, thanks for getting back to me. I understand.