# How to Save Great Expectations Html validation results to Databricks DBFS or Azure Blob

Tags: azure-databricks, great-expectations

Sometime ago I asked the question

> How to Save Great Expectations results to File From Apache Spark -
> With Data Docs

[How to Save Great Expectations results to File From Apache Spark - With Data Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68023413/how-to-save-great-expectations-results-to-file-from-apache-spark-with-data-doc/68364259?noredirect=1#comment120855332_68364259)

The answers centred on viewing the results in Databricks, however I would like to know how to save the Html results to file - either on Databricks DBFS or on Azure ADLS / Blob.

Alex Ott, mentioned the following:

> If you're not using Databricks, then you can render the data into HTML
> and store it as files stored somewhere

However, I'm not sure if he was suggesting that its not possible to store the files if I'm not using Databricks?

In any case, can someone show me how to store / save the file:

I tried the code below but I got the error message:

```
ResourceNotFoundError: The specified filesystem does not exist.
```

and the error pointed to:

```
file.create_file()
```

The code I uses was as follows:

```
with open('/dbfs/mnt/lake/RAW/pitstops_suite.html', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

file = DataLakeFileClient.from_connection_string("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=adlsbiukadlsdev;AccountKey=sz8sRd66FLYMjjqa7GfxW1V/ZyMWdmc0YQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", file_system_name="polybase", file_path="pitstops_suite.html")

##htmp test
file.create_file()
file.append_data(html, offset=0, length=len(html))
file.flush_data(len(html))
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
#Engine
from great_expectations.dataset.sparkdf_dataset import SparkDFDataset
#Doc related
from great_expectations.render.renderer import ProfilingResultsPageRenderer, ExpectationSuitePageRenderer
from great_expectations.render.view import DefaultJinjaPageView

df = SparkDFDataset(df)

df.expect...
df.expect...

validations = df.validate()
    
profiling_html_filepath = "path"

document_model = ProfilingResultsPageRenderer().render(validations)
dbutils.fs.mkdirs(profiling_html_filepath)
dbutils.fs.put(profiling_html_filepath, document_model, True)
```