# How to open index.html file in databricks or browser?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, great-expectations

I am trying to open index.html file through databricks. Can someone please let me know how to deal with it? I am trying to use GX with databricks and currently, data bricks store this file here: `dbfs:/great_expectations/uncommitted/data_docs/local_site/index.html` I want to send `index.html` file to stakeholder

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you need to copy the whole folder as there should be images, etc.  Simplest way to do that is to use [Databricks CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/) `fs cp` command to access DBFS and copy files to the local storage. Like this:

```
databricks fs cp -r 'dbfs:/.....' local_name
```

To open file directly in the notebook you can use something like this (note that `dbfs:/` should be replaced with `/dbfs/`):

```py
with open("/dbfs/...", "r") as f:
  data = "".join([l for l in f])

displayHTML(data)
```

but this will break links to images.  Alternatively you can follow [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68023413/how-to-save-great-expectations-results-to-file-from-apache-spark-with-data-doc/68364259#68364259) to display Data docs inside the notebook.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am able to open it on my windows machine through databricks CLI  but I want to share that file with stakeholders so is there any way to directly open that file in the data brick itself or in the browser from databricks

Comment: Yeah it works with broken links